# android: adb pull file path limitation for windows?

Tags: android

When I pull some file from phone using adb pull, I got error like:cannot create 'some file': No such file or directory

The detail is: I create a file named "a.txt", under folder /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/100ANDRO/vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv, the "v....v" is a folder I create under /mnt/sdcard/dcim/100ANDRO/, then I open command terminal and switch to C:/ and run the command : C:\aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa>adb pull /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/100ANDRO/vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv  folderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolder

here: a..........a is a folder I create in C:\ disk,  the v....v is the folder I create under /mnt/sdcard/dcim/100ANDRO/, the "folder...folder...folder" is the target folder I want to create.

The result is:pull: building file list...

```
pull: /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/100ANDRO/vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv/a.txt -> folderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolder/a.txt
cannot create 'folderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderf
olderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolder\a.txt': No such file or directory
```

but if the target folder length is shorter, the command will success!

```
C:\aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa>adb pull /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/100ANDRO/vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv folderfolderfolderfolderfolderfo
lderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfold
pull: building file list...
pull: /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/100ANDRO/vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv/a.txt -> folderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolder
folderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfolderfold/a.txt
1 file pulled. 0 files skipped.
0 KB/s (12 bytes in 0.070s)
```

Why this happen? Is it a defect for adb.exe ? please help, really appreciated for that.

Comment: is this because the file name tooooo  long ?

Answer (score 0):

See the link below:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx

> In the Windows API (with some exceptions discussed in the following paragraphs), the maximum length for a path is MAX_PATH, which is defined as 260 characters.

Are your paths crossing 260/?

Comment: thanks for you answer, it helps. but HOW TO USE THE LONG PATH IN PYTHON FOR WINDOWS?

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this issue with cmd.exe + 260 character group policy editor/registry fix + reboot. Once I switched to powershell I was able to `adb pull` my files from my phone. If that doesn't work, try git bash.